How to fix OperationalError: database is locked?
I have set up a database connection to SQLite with SQLAlchemy:
DATABASE = 'sqlite:////someaddress.db'
db = create_engine(DATABASE, echo=True, connect_args={'timeout': 15})
engine = db.raw_connection()

My script polls the database:
POSTCODES = pd.read_sql("SELECT pcd, pcd2, pcds, LAT, LONG FROM postcodes", engine)

It does this without problem. But when I try:
self.df.to_sql(name='vouchers', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)

I get this error:

OperationalError: database is locked

How do I resolve this error?

Why would you call your Engine object db and your DBAPI (raw) connection object engine ?

Probably easiest to use a context manager. You don't want to hold a connection forever so connect and then let the context manager close the connection.
I think SQLAlchemy wants your SQL statements wrapped in text() when you pass them. Use variable names that match the contents; engine for an Engine() and conn or connection for a Connection().
#...
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

DATABASE = 'sqlite:////someaddress.db'
engine = create_engine(DATABASE, echo=True, connect_args={'timeout': 15})

# No commit, just reading, after context manager ends the connection is returned to the pool.
with engine.connect() as conn:
    POSTCODES = pd.read_sql(text("SELECT pcd, pcd2, pcds, LAT, LONG FROM postcodes"), conn)

# Commit after writing, after context manager ends the connection is returned to the pool.
with engine.connect() as conn:
    self.df.to_sql(name='vouchers', con=conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
    conn.commit()

Connections documentation.

I tried that, and thought it was logical. Same as file handling.

But it didn't stop the error. Is it worth creating a new database and transferring every table from the old database into it?

I don't use sqlite that much but after reading about it seems that concurrency is not its strength and get very complicated.  Are you trying to do many simultaneous writes?

I'm not. Should only be one at a time. That's what confuses me. I'm going to try pooling connection to one connection and see if that works.
